# Does L mean anything other than "the inverse of the elimination steps"?

Tags: linear-algebra

Having the LU factorization of the matrix $A$ on hand makes it really easy to solve problems in the form $Ax = b$. Since $A = LU$, we can write $LUx = b$, then solve $Ly = b$ for $y$ followed by $Ux = y$ for $x$.

This makes sense if you happen to be given $A$ along with its decomposition $LU$. But in practice, my textbook (Strang 4e, section 1.5) is giving me *only* $A$. To solve the matrix equation, I first write out the elimination matrices that correspond to the Gaussian row operations that will turn $A$ into $U$. Multiplying these in the correct order yields $L^{-1}$, which I then use to solve the whole system in one shot by back substitution: $Ux = L^{-1}b$.

This way of doing things gets me the correct answers, but I feel like I'm not "really" doing LU decomposition as Strang intends for me to. For one thing, while the textbook hasn't officially introduced inverse matrices at this point, I don't see how I can factor $A$ into $LU$ without first finding $L$'s inverse.

More to the point, I never actually determine or use $L$ itself, since the inverse is what solves the $Ly = b$ equation anyway. When the textbook asks me to provide L, I have been writing out the individual matrices that will *undo* the elimination steps and multiplying them together in the reverse order, which seems pointless.

So, I have two questions:

1. When solving $Ax = b$, why bother taking the inverse of the Gaussian elimination steps (that is, $[L^{-1}]^{-1}$) to find $L$ when $L^{-1}$ (the elimination matrix) is what we actually use in the end? Why do we prefer $A = LU$ to $L^{-1}A = U$?
2. Does L mean anything other than "the inverse of the elimination steps"? Can it be computed more simply? The advantage of LU decomposition over Gaussian elimination disappears if finding L requires you to figure out all the Gaussian elimination steps in the first place.

A few notes:

- I know L and U can be computed more *quickly* than Gaussian elimination. My question isn't about computing time; it's about whether the fast algorithms that find L can yield any insight into the information present in L.
- There was a [very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266355/necessity-advantage-of-lu-decomposition-over-gaussian-elimination) asking why LU decomposition is preferred to elimination. The accepted answer argues that the reason for using LU substitution is so that you can adapt quickly to any $b$ vector. But the process I've described above also doesn't deal with $b$ until the last step, so I believe my question is distinct.