# What is the advantage of LU decomposition over storing the elimination matrix directly?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

The answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266355/necessity-advantage-of-lu-decomposition-over-gaussian-elimination) indicate that one of the advantages of LU decomposition is that the algorithm do not redo the elimination steps.

Why do we insist on storing the factorized form of $L$ and $U$?  Why not just save $E$ and $U$, where

\begin{align}
Ax = b
&\implies EAx = Eb && \text{(multiply both sides by $E$)} \\
&\implies Ux = Eb && \text{(since $EA = U$)}
\end{align}

As you can see, we just need to store $U$ and the elimination matrix $E$, so whenever we have a new matrix $b$ on the right-hand side, we can just multiply it out with $E$, and use back-subsitution to solve for $x$. What's advantage of storing $L$ and $U$ over storing $E$ and $U$?

Answer (score 3):

Note that in your case, the matrix $E$ is $L^{-1}$. So one might just go even further and store $U^{-1}$ as well or even $A^{-1}=U^{-1}L^{-1}$.

So why not just store $A^{-1}$? In a word, **accuracy**. A matrix $A$ has a so-called [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) $\kappa(A)$. The error $\| x_{\rm computed} - x\|$ in solving $Ax = b$ is roughly $\kappa(A)\times 10^{-16}$ in double precision arithmetic (more generally, $10^{-16}$ is roughly the unit roundoff for your floating point number system). However, even when $\kappa(A)$ is large, conventional $LU$ factorization with back- and forward-substitution tends to be backwards stable in the sense that the residual norm is small: $\|Ax_{\rm computed} - b\| \approx 10^{-16}$. In some applications, a small residual is more important than a small error, so this backwards stability is a desirable property.

Unfortunately, if you compute and store $A^{-1} = U^{-1}L^{-1}$, then the computed solution is (usually) no longer backwards stable and the residual is much larger $\|Ax_{\rm computed} - b\| \approx \kappa(A)\times 10^{-16}$. The error $\| x_{\rm computed} - x\|$ is usually of the same magnitude, but is usually a bit larger than if we just did back substitution.

So if we store $E=L^{-1}$, our residual norm will usually be higher. But not higher like $\|Ax_{\rm computed} - b\| \approx \kappa(A)\times 10^{-16}$, but higher like $\|Ax_{\rm computed} - b\| \approx \kappa(L)\times 10^{-16}$. We pay for the condition number of $L$ not $A$. In practice, $L$ is *usually* fairly well-conditioned even if $A$ is not. For instance, in some tests I did with a [randsvd](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html) random matrix $A$ with condition number $10^{14}$, the condition number of $L$ computed with partial pivoting is only like $10^2$. So the residual norm is only like $100\times $ larger than with back- and forward- substitution.

There are other reasons to prefer storing $L$ over $E$. For example, if $L$ is a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), $E$ may be less sparse and thus more computational costly to multiply by.

You're *usually* not losing a lot of accuracy or speed by the approach you advocate, but it's not clear exactly what you're *gaining* by your approach since you are losing *something* in accuracy by storing $E$ instead of $L$. Unless you're in a setting where you have a good reason to use $E$ instead of $L$ (which do exist), I would suggest sticking with $L$.

Comment: Your comment on my now-deleted answer was right, I was overgeneralizing from the case of an elementary matrix.

Comment: Also the memory usage remark is largely irrelevant; LU decomposition is fundamentally a dense algorithm except in very specific scenarios, so you generally plan to have at least a full matrix's worth of memory to devote to it.

Comment: @Ian If I do Cholesky factorization of the 2D discrete Poisson problem (or more general 2D finite difference algorithms on a regular Cartesian grid) in the nested dissection ordering, $L$ has only $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ nonzero entries. In 3D, it's $\mathcal{O}(n^{4/3})$. This seems like an important example to me.

Comment: That's interesting, though that's already getting into a situation where you are doing a partially specialized implementation, so your black box LU algorithm doesn't perform ideally.